# A possible defining characteristic of primitive roots.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

If $n$ is a primitive root $\bmod p$ ($p$ is an odd prime ) does there always exist a least residue $t$ such that $n^t \equiv t \pmod p$ ?

Comment: Viewing $t$ as residue $\bmod p$ makes little sense as the exponent should rather be considered $\bmod {p-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$.
For any $r\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$, find $a$ with $n^a\equiv r\pmod p$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists $t\in\mathbb N_0$ with $t\equiv a\pmod{p-1}$ and $t\equiv r\pmod p$. For such $t$, we have $n^t\equiv t\pmod p$. As is the case for any nonempty set of $\mathbb N_0$, there certainly is a minimal such $t$.

Comment: If there exists no u | (n^u) = u (mod p) then n is not a primitive root mod p. Is this true?

Comment: If for any m, n^m = m(v) mod(p) and p does not divide (v-1) then m is not a primitive root mod(p). Is this true?

Comment: Another way to ask the question ; if for any u > 0 ,  p  does not divide (m^u - u) then m is not a primitive root mod p.